# VBS Case Statement is failing

Tags: vbscript, case

This case statement is failing...it is like it never even sees it any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Dim Runmode

Set objFileToRead = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile("D:\Program Files (x86)\Logility\SPC8.0\Input\FG352F.txt",1)
RunMode = objFileToRead.ReadAll()
objFileToRead.Close
Set objFileToRead = Nothing
MsgBox(RunMode)


select Case RunMode
  Case "D"
     Set oShell = CreateObject("WSCript.shell")
     oShell.run "D:\Scripts\RTL_DAILY.bat"

  Case "W"
     Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WSCript.shell")
     oShell.run "D:\Scripts\RTL_WEEKLY.bat"

  Case "M"
     Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WSCript.shell")
     oShell.run "D:\Scripts\RTL_MONTHLY.bat"
End Select
```

Comment: What's the actual content of the `RunMode` variable. You print it with `MsgBox` but that won't tell you if there's a whitespace at the beginning / end of the string. You're doing a `Select Case` on exact values but what you read from the file may be different.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the file contains a single letter like "M" and perhaps an EOL, use .ReadLine() to get rid of the EOL automagically.

In general, a Case Else to catch (and dump)  surprises is always a good idea.